# Android app with eclipse project dependency

Tags: android, eclipse, buildpath

I have an Android app which uses a jar library generated from another Eclipse project.

But is it possible to directly reference this project instead of using an intermediate jar ?

When I do that, the build succeeds but I get VerifyErrors at runtime saying the classes of my external project can't be found...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can directly reference this project by setting it as library. To do so:

1. Right click on your desired library project, choose properties and mark checkbox 'isLibrary'
2. Then just simply right click on you project, go to properties and add those library project

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ADT supports libraries in form of shareable source code and resources, not just .jar. Please see Android Developer website, especially [Managing Projects -> Library Projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) article.